# If Without Else in Procedures

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

**I have Following Procedure:**

```
CREATE PROC spInvTotal2
   @DateVar smalldatetime = NULL
AS
IF @DateVar IS NULL
    SELECT @DateVar = MIN(InvoiceDate) FROM Invoices;
SELECT SUM(InvoiceTotal)
FROM Invoices
WHERE InvoiceDate >= @DateVar;
```

Here we have **IF** statement but not **ELSE**. What happens if **@DateVar IS NULL** or **@DateVar IS NOT NULL**?

And We have two **SELECT** Statements. Do they run both?

So if I insert **ELSE** the meaning of code will be the same?

```
CREATE PROC spInvTotal2
   @DateVar smalldatetime = NULL
AS
IF @DateVar IS NULL
    SELECT @DateVar = MIN(InvoiceDate) FROM Invoices;
ELSE
SELECT SUM(InvoiceTotal)
FROM Invoices
WHERE InvoiceDate >= @DateVar;
```

Comment: The query will run anyway, thus you should use `Begin ... End`

Comment: Did you try it? What happened?

Comment: what is stopping you for trying this out yourself ?

Comment: Please don't post multiple questions after you get answers.

Comment: Why are you adding more questions to your question but aren't responding the the answers and comments you've received and why are you not just trying yourself? Test and find out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just another option is to use IsNull()

```
SELECT SUM(InvoiceTotal)
FROM Invoices
WHERE InvoiceDate >= IsNull(@DateVar,( Select  MIN(InvoiceDate) FROM Invoices ) )
```

Comment: It is an option, but given the optimizer's spotty record for turning things like this into proper index seeks, typically not a good one. (In fact, it's possible this `IF` is there exactly to avoid this issue.)

Comment: Interesting, but couldn't the same be written even shorter like this:

Comment: SELECT SUM(InvoiceTotal) FROM Invoices WHERE @DateVar is null or InvoiceDate >= DateVar

Comment: @Morten That would be perfectly valid as well.   There is seldom one true answer in life  :)

Answer (score 3):

If you don't use `begin ... end` this query will run anyway

```
SELECT SUM(InvoiceTotal)
FROM Invoices
WHERE InvoiceDate >= @DateVar;
```

which mean in both cases (`@DateVar IS NULL` or `@DateVar IS NOT NULL`) it will run.

> And We have two SELECT Statements. Do they run both?

The first query will run **only** when the condition is met, and the second query will run in both cases.

---

Conclution:

- If `@DateVar IS NULL` both queries will run.
- If `@DateVar IS NOT NULL` only the second query will run.

---

<sub>Since you don't ask for how to solve it (only ask for what happen) I did not give a solution</sub>

Answer (score 0):

if @DateVar IS NULL ---> the logic below will run

```
SELECT @DateVar = MIN(InvoiceDate) FROM Invoices;
```

or @DateVar IS NOT NULL ---> the logic under IF block will be skipped. And rest of the code will run.

So the better practice is to use the if block

like

```
Begin
 IF @DateVar IS NULL
    SELECT @DateVar = MIN(InvoiceDate) FROM Invoices;
END
```